# Xcode freezes on project load after installing facebook pods

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

Other posts solutions didn't help with my problem.

After i installed these pods

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

my Project.xcworkspace and even the Project.xcodeproj won't load. Xcode freezes during loading the project.

Unfortunately even after uninstalling the pods again, Xcode still freezes on project loadup.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Yes of course, doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1

I hope the last session was saved somewhere, In most cases just remove the Autosave Information's content

~/Library/Autosave Information

Solution 2

quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Solution 3

If your project is sync with icloud please unsync from iCloud

Comment: quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: doesn't help :(

Comment: If your project is sync with icloud please unsync from iCloud

Comment: that did solve the problem, thanks! Do you know why that's the case?

Comment: Coz local copy and iCloud copy is different thats cause some setting issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136480/discussion-between-balagurubaran-and-bioaim).